# Failed to install package PyGObject

Tags: windows-10, pycharm, gtk3, pygobject

I am not sure if the error in red colour is visible, it says "raise SystemExit Error: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is essential."
[image]

I tried installing the latest version of GTK3 as mentioned in the link below but still it shows the same error.

[How to install PyGObject through PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181557/how-to-install-pygobject-through-pycharm)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I didn't install PyGobject through PyCharm, but downloading and installing the project [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/). Keep in mind it is for Python 3.4 only (32 bit or 64 bit), it doesn't work with Python 3.5.
I'm able to write code with PyCharm without any problem. The only small issue is PyCharm isn't able to detect the packages installed, such as gi, Gtk, Glib, so it shows some warnings. But it works.

Comment: Thank you so much @pozzugno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the problem with python new version 3.5 and so I installed version 3.4 and now its working fine. Hope this answer also helps others.